# React component not showing on browser

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, frontend, react-component

In very simple words, one of my component is rendering successfully but another one is not showing on browser.
 Here is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import Top from './Top'
import Bottom from './Bottom'
import Left from './Left'
import Right from './Right'
import Center from './Center'
import Extra from './Extra'


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <Top />
      <Center />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

In above, `<Top />` component is rendering/viewing on browser but JSX for `<Center />` component showing in inspect but unable to view in browser.
Here is my Center.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import lamp from './images/thumbs/masonry/lamp-400.jpg'


class Center extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>

      <section class="s-content">

          <div class="row masonry-wrap">
              <div class="masonry">

                  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>

                  <article class="masonry__brick entry format-standard" data-aos="fade-up">

                      <div class="entry__thumb">
                          <a href="single-standard.html" class="entry__thumb-link">
                              <img src={lamp} alt=""/>
                          </a>
                      </div>

                      <div class="entry__text">
                          <div class="entry__header">

                              <div class="entry__date">
                                  <a href="single-standard.html">December 15, 2017</a>
                              </div>
                              <h1 class="entry__title"><a href="single-standard.html">Just a Standard Format Post.</a></h1>

                          </div>
                          <div class="entry__excerpt">
                              <p>
                                  Lorem ipsum Sed eiusmod esse aliqua sed incididunt aliqua incididunt mollit id et sit proident dolor nulla sed commodo est ad minim elit reprehenderit nisi officia aute incididunt velit sint in aliqua...
                              </p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="entry__meta">
                              <span class="entry__meta-links">
                                  <a href="category.html">Design</a>
                                  <a href="category.html">Photography</a>
                              </span>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                  </article>
</div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-full">
                  <nav class="pgn">
                      <ul>
                          <li><a class="pgn__prev" href="#0">Prev</a></li>
                          <li><a class="pgn__num" href="#0">1</a></li>
                          <li><span class="pgn__num current">2</span></li>
                          <li><a class="pgn__num" href="#0">3</a></li>
                          <li><a class="pgn__num" href="#0">4</a></li>
                          <li><a class="pgn__num" href="#0">5</a></li>
                          <li><span class="pgn__num dots">…</span></li>
                          <li><a class="pgn__num" href="#0">8</a></li>
                          <li><a class="pgn__next" href="#0">Next</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </nav>
              </div>
          </div>

      </section>
      </React.Fragment>

    )
  }
}


export default Center
```

Here i am attaching screenshot of my browser.

[image]

Upper black portion is `<Top />` component and below that is `<Center />` component which is not visible in the browser.

It could be a small mistake but i am new to react and i am not able to find what could be the reason. help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure there is no `display: none` ?

Comment: I am using templates and i did not change anything in css yet.

Comment: can u change as the answer posted, and see what happens?

Comment: I tried but it's still not working.

Comment: Ok for debugging purposed please add `<section className="s-content" styles={{diplay: "block"}}>` .. ? Now what?

Comment: <section className="s-content" styles={{diplay: "block"}}> Not works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178619/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-jitendra).

Answer (score 2):

You should change all class attributes to className

Answer (score 1):

In react class is keyword that is reserved so you can't use class like in ordinary html. Here JSX is used in react and className is used to specify any styling class. Hence you should try converting all class to className expect at declaration of component `class Center extends React.Component`